# Find inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1   & 1 & 1 &  \cdots & 1\\
    0 & 1  & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
    0 & 0  & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find $A^{-1}$. How could I do that, knowing that matrix A has size $n \times n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the matrix

$$B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1   & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 1  & -1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0  & 1  & \ddots&0\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \ddots & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

One easily verifies that
$$AB = I_n$$ and $$BA = I_n$$

Thus $B=A^{-1}$

*Edit:* How to come up with $B$? First of all you should compute some inverse matrices, maybe for the cases $n = 2$ and $n=3$. In order you may see a pattern and get an idea how a candidate $B$ for an inverse of $A$ should look like. Just verify $BA = I_n$ and $AB = I_n$ and you will end up with $A^{-1} = B$.

Comment: thanks, but i don't need the answer, i need to know how to come to that answer. the process

Comment: @manabou11  The process is to try it on some examples like $n=2$ and $n=3$, come up with the matrix $B$ and verify that the claim was true.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the row operations that you would need to do to reduce this matrix to the identity matrix. Starting with $A$, the way that you would force the first row to be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}$ would be to subtract the second row from the first row (in other words, replace the first row with the first row minus the second row). Similarly, to make the $i$th row have zeroes everywhere except in the $i$th entry (which is what the $i$th row of the identity matrix looks like), we should replace the $i$th row of $A$ with the $i$th row of $A$ minus the $(i + 1)$th row of $A$.

Thus, the matrix of row operations that reduces $A$ to the identity is the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that we did not have to change the $n$th row, as it was already equal to the $n$th row of the identity matrix. Of course, the matrix that reduces $A$ to the identity matrix is $A^{-1}$, so indeed the matrix above is $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Use the adjugate matrix formula, as the minors are easy to calculate.

Comment: @manabou11 I can elaborate on this strategy, if you're not sure how to conclude.